# Save the final value of a linked list to a variable in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I want to save the final value on a LinkedList of 5000000 integers by using an iterator. For this assignment, I need to traverse through the entire list (I know this is not the most efficient way). Here is the code that I have:

```
//method 1:
        ListIterator ls = list.listIterator();
        while (ls.hasNext()) {
            var save = ls.next(); //my attempt to save the final value
            ls.next();
        }
```

What is the best way for me to save the value at the last index to a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListIterator<Integer> ls = list.listIterator();
int last = -1;
while (ls.hasNext()) {
  last = ls.next();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way for me to save the value at the last index to a
> variable?

Keeping in mind that there are `5.000.000 elements` the most **efficient** way to access the last element is to make use of the fact that **LinkedList** implements the **Deque** interface:

```
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        .....    
        Integer last = ((Deque<Integer>) list).peekLast();
```

**Note:**

- any element in the list could be `null` and application will crash if you'll try to assign `null` to an `int` variable;
- in order to invoke the method `peekLast()` first you have to cast the list to the appropriate type.

But, if for this task you `have to use a` **`ListIterator`** at all costs, then I advise you to fix the code you've provided like that:

```
    public static Optional<Integer> getLast(List<Integer> list) {
        ListIterator<Integer> ls = list.listIterator();
        Integer last = null;
        while (ls.hasNext()) {
            last = ls.next();
        }
        return Optional.ofNullable(last);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, don't save the value as you go through the list:

```
while (ls.hasNext()) {
  ls.next();
}
// Assuming the list isn't empty:
var last = ls.previous();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
list.getLast();
```

to get the last item from the list.

Comment: "I need to traverse through the entire list (I know this is not the most efficient way)"